# EAGLE Square hole

Tags: eaglecad, square, drill

I want to make a square hole in the middle of my PCB, but when I choose to make a drill or hole is only a circle! Isn't there a option or a ULP file that allow me to do a square hole? I can't find anything on EAGLE....

Regards,
Luis

Comment: That would typically be defined in the same way you define the board outline. It is not a drill, but a routed cutout.

Comment: Get a special drill bit, see here : https://www.tool-rank.com/tool-blog/cool-tools/how-to-drill-a-square-hole-201203141140/

Comment: What size hole? And why do you want it? (No, this isn't meant as a nasty remark, but knowing the size and your reasons for wanting the hole may help others provide a useful response.)

Comment: This is difficult to achieve in practice regardless of your PCB package. If you can accept rounded corners then holes can be milled (or routed) instead of drilled but talk to your board manufacturer.  The only time I have had truly rectangular (or square) holes on any of my PCBs has been when I had high volumes and could afford a punch tool to create the holes.

Comment: I want to place this module on my PCB , but it has components on the lower part ! https://leopardimaging.com/product/li-imx274-mipi-m12/

Comment: If you have not looked at the website yet it may help. https://www.element14.com/community/thread/42375/l/eagle-cad-non-circle-through-hole-pads?displayFullThread=true

Comment: Autodesk has a blog post about this: https://www.autodesk.com/products/eagle/blog/what-you-didnt-know-about-eagle-slotted-holes/

Answer (score 3):

Square drill bits are rather rare...

The square hole will have to be milled.  Discuss this with your board shop to see how they would like the hole documented (or if they can/are willing to do this at all.)

Answer (score 0):

Define corner radius or diameter then route a square

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about Eagle software but PADS and Altium use what is called a board cutout to create any geometry of hole or cutout. I would look for something like a board cutout in Eagle as well.

Comment: Recent versions of Altium also allows pad holes to be "square" (actually a square with rounded corners) or "slot".

Answer (score 0):

First ask yourself what sort of hole do you want?

If what you are after is a non-plated cut out I would just draw it on the same layer you draw the board outline on.

If you want it to be plated then I expect that in the absesence of specific support in your PCB design tool your best bet is to draw it on a seperate layer and tell your PCB vendor what you want.

Note that even if you draw a precisely square hole that will not be what you get back from the manufacturer. The hole will be milled with a milling cutter of finite diameter. So the corners will inevitablly end up with a radius at least that of the cutter.

Answer (score -1):

The only way you can do that is to create a component in your library and select the pad as a square instead of a round one. In the tool bar you will not find square holes because they are not used, although there are possibilities to choose a via as a square.
I suggest you use the hole as round unless you have a very particular need

Comment: You seem to be talking about making a square pad (copper area), rather than the square hole that the OP wants.